# Create css files compatible with multiple browsers automatically

Tags: css

Is there any solution that allows you to design a webpage (with, say, a wysiwyg editor) and then automatically compile the design as one or several css file(s) compatible across multiple browsers?

Comment: I sure as hell hope not otherwise I'm out of a job :)

Comment: Such solution does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, using a WYSIWYG editor will generate superfluous entries to your HTML mark-up and create inefficient stylesheets that don't make use of CSS shorthand.

The best way to create stylesheets that are compatible across multiple browers sadly just comes with experience. By knowing the quirks of IE6 and IE7 you automatically cater for them as you create the stylesheet.

A good [reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) will help to erradicate any default differences between browsers, such as line height, body padding, etc.

The exact solution you're after doesn't exist (yet).

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think so. There are some CSS frameworks trying to deal with this issue, the more popular one I know is called [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/en/). Some JavaScript libraries are dealing with cross browser CSS issues, too (don't know a particular example at the moment though).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use PHP to write the content of a .CSS file.